# Vertical IconTabBar in SAPUI5

Tags: vertical-alignment, menubar, sapui5

I am programming a SAPUI5 application and I would like achieve a vertical menu seemed `IconTabBar`. IconTabBar only allows me horizontal configuration.

Can I simulate that behavior with another components?

I was trying to create a "different" `IconTabBar` that only has one `IconTabFilter` as an aggregation and add it in a Vertical layout but it isn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, **No**.

There is no out-of-box solution for your requirement. The [IconTabBar](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.IconTabBar.html) is only available in the horizontal orientation and there isn't a provision (atleast not yet) to change it to *vertical*.

PS: If there is something that you have tried in particular, post code snippets to help others analyze better.